# advantage of closing an index and restoring from snapshot elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

One of my index in elasticsearch has a shard which is unassigned therefore that data is not available and my cluster status is red ,

I want to restore this index i have a snapshot of the same , so i want to restore this index from the snapshot

Now i see 2 options of doing so

1. delete current index and then restore from backup
2. close current index and restore from backup

considering my index number of shards remain the same what is the advantage of closing the index and restoring rather than deleting it and then restoring it.

Answer (score 0):

in your case it has no advantage

in other cases, you may want to close the index, restore to a previous state, delete the restore and then reopen the original, thereby saving a bit of extra work